# How to change a url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

i have this url:

```
 merchantstore.php?merchant=100&product=208
```

that i want to convert to:

```
/merchant-store-name/product-name
```

where merchant-store-name replace ?merchant=100 and product-name replace &product=208

How do i do that in htacess file.

Comment: is `$1 = merchant-store-name` and `$2 = product-name` ?

Comment: You need to be a lot more descriptive.  What is `$1`, `$2`? What do they map to?

Comment: Give us an example set of urls (not with placeholders, with some real or close to real values).

Comment: I Have corrected the question and improved my accepted rate as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to use a PHP-based approach. In the .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule (.*) switchboard.php?orig_uri=$1
```

This captures the entire requested uri, and kind of forwards it to a central switchboard. Then in the switchboard.php you have access to the requested uri, which you can explode() along '/' signs, then look up the id-s associated with the names in you database.

```
$components = explode('/', $_GET['orig_uri']);
list( $merchant_name, $product_name ) = $components;

// get merchant id and product id from your database

// and serve suitable content by include-ing:
include 'merchant.php';
```

This is a simple method, and rather easy to scale. It also has the added advantage that no mod-rewrite magic is required.

Don't forget to add proper error-handling.